# Tags and autocomplete on node.js with Jade and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, node.js, autocomplete, tags, pug

i'm trying to implement a tagging feature like here on stackoverflow, but the combination of jade, jquery is not something i can overcome so far... I am using bootstrap so bootstrap-tagmanager seems a great choice but i can't implement it. I've found this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vt2z4/ but even with this i simply can't. Has anyone done it or have any suggestions?

The fiddle code is

```
<input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tagsManager"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Pisa,Rome" name="hiddenTagList">
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tagsManager").tagsManager({
         prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome"],
         CapitalizeFirstLetter: true,
         preventSubmitOnEnter: true,
         typeahead: true,
         typeaheadAjaxSource: null,
         typeaheadSource: ["Pisa", "Rome", "Milan", "Florence", "New York", "Paris",      "Berlin", "London", "Madrid"],
         delimeters: [44, 188, 13],
         backspace: [8],
         blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
         blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
         hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA'
     });
});
```

Comment: Hi, i had same problem too, and finally fix the problem, pls someone who needs help, refer to my question , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907373/jquery-autocomplete-with-jade-pug/52908569#52908569

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep it simple at first. Let us know what exactly doesn't work for you and post your code (not working example code) so we can actually help.

### Basic example

If using twitter bootstrap begin with a simple static data test by using data attributes like this (don't forget the js and css includes required for bootstrap)

```
<input type='text' data-provide='typeahead' autocomplete='off'  data-items='4'  
data-source='["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]'/>
```

### Resources

Some more examples: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

typeahead doc: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was working on a [POC](https://github.com/sumveds/weather-report/)(a simple weather reporting webapp) using express, jade, bootstrap and tagmanager. I am able to make the **tags input field** work and I have shared the POC on GitHub.

The jade template [file](https://github.com/sumveds/weather-report/blob/master/views/weather.jade) looks something like below code snippet.

```
block content
  .jumbotron
    h2 Weather report
    h3 Welcome to the weather report page!

  div.container
    .navbar.navbar-default(role='navigation')
      .container-fluid
        .collapse.navbar-collapse
          form(name="report", class="navbar-form navbar-left", action="/weather/report", method="POST")
            input(type="text", name="cities", class="form-control", data-role="tagsinput", placeholder="Type in city and press enter...")
            input(type="submit", class="btn btn-default", value="Submit")

  div.footer
```

One of the attribute of the **cities** input field is `data-role="tagsinput"`.

The input field looks something like below image:
[image]

Then, I have a route(routes/weather.js) which will be hit once user clicks on the submit button.

I hope this will be helpful for you. Please comment if anyone needs further clarification.